# How to set multiple buttons, textblocks and textboxes underneath each other in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel, dockpanel

Right now I have the following:

```
<DockPanel Height="150">

    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Padding="5" Margin="5 0 5 0" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Submit" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Padding="5" Text="DVM Positive Readout" />

    <Border Height="25" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="DVM_Positive_ReadOut" LostKeyboardFocus="DVM_Positive_ReadOut_LostKeyboardFocus" />
    </Border>

    <Border Height="25" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="DVM_Negavtive_ReadOut" LostKeyboardFocus="DVM_Negative_ReadOut_LostKeyboardFocus" />
    </Border>

</DockPanel>
```

Which results in:
[image: How it currently is]

I want to have two submit buttons and two textblocks. The Textboxes are correctly stacked, though it would be nice if they were centered.

Like this:
[image: How I want it to be]

Comment: You can easily achieve this with designer. Whats the problem

Comment: Have you considered using a grid?

Comment: @croxy I tried the grid and that worked as well. So thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using StackPanel with its horizontal or vertical attribute:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left"
                       Padding="5"
                       Text="DVM Positive Readout" 
                       Width="150"/>
            <Border Height="25"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Width="150"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         x:Name="DVM_Positive_ReadOut"
                         LostKeyboardFocus="DVM_Positive_ReadOut_LostKeyboardFocus" />
            </Border>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Padding="5"
                    Margin="5 0 5 0"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Content="Submit"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left"
                       Padding="5"
                       Text="DVM Negative Readout"
                       Width="150" />
            <Border Height="25"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Width="150"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         x:Name="DVM_Negavtive_ReadOut"
                         LostKeyboardFocus="DVM_Negative_ReadOut_LostKeyboardFocus" />
            </Border>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Padding="5"
                    Margin="5 0 5 0"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Content="Submit"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: I just added  '<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">' and I have what I need! Thank you =)

Comment: I have only 2 horizontal StackPanels and no vertical one. (Used for a grid row with filter options.) Then it does **NOT WORK**. But here I found a sweet solution with an **Attached Property**, by which you can define different scopes for each pair of TextBox and Button. ... http://neilmosafi.blogspot.com/2007/04/default-buttons-in-wpf-and-multiple.html